# video download on android that can only be played from the app

Tags: java, android, video

my app is streaming videos from url, but I'd also like to be able to download them and see them offline.

Is it possible to make them available just for my app?

These videos should not be shared or transfered to other devices, they should be played from the app that downloaded them only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to store the data in a private folder on the device that only your app can access.

#### Example

```
String FILENAME = "My File Name";
YourVideoDataType video;
FileOutputStream fOutputStream = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fOutputStream.write(video.getBytes());
fOutputStream.close();
```

Also, make sure to include the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your Android Manifest.